# To do it will be hard

Tags: infinitives

I can say the sentence:

> It will be hard to do it

But can I say it so?

> To do it will be hard

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct.

> It will be hard to do it

sounds more natural. The word order is more usual.

Use the second example if you want to shift the emphasize somehow, or if you want to sound (a little) like Yoda.

Comment: It's cool when one can be Yoda:). Thank you!

Comment: If like Yoda can be, cool it is, indeed! :D